# Remover todos elementos do list sem o método Clean(), tem como?

Tags: c#, lista, arraylist

Por exemplo eu queria remover os elementos da lista dessa forma:

```
public class List : MonoBehaviour {

List<string> inventário = new List<string>();

void Start () {



    for(int i = 0;i<=10;i++){
        inventário.Add("slot" + i);
    }

    Debug.Log(inventário[1]);

    for(int i=0;i<inventário.Count;i++){
        inventário.Remove(inventário[i]);
    }
```

Mas por algum motivo ele deixa apenas 5 elementos no array list.

Comment: E por que você faria isto?

Comment: Para aprender cada vez mais sobre o comando list e também para não perder a prática do loop for.

Comment: Não me convenceu da necessidade. Acho que aprendeu fazer algo errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque isso:

```
for(int i=0;i<inventário.Count;i++){
    inventário.Remove(inventário[i]);
}
```

Por isso:

```
while (inventário.Count != 0) {
    inventário.Remove(inventário[0]);
}
```

O motivo é que no seu primeiro `for`, ele remove o elemento na posição 0, mas daí o elemento que estava na posição 1 vai para a 0. Depois você vai para a posição 1 e remove o elemento que estava lá, e com isso o que estava na 2 vai para 1, e assim por diante. Como resultado, a cada iteração você eliminava um elemento e também poupava um outro elemento, eliminando só a metade deles (os que tinham índices pares).

Já nesse `while`, ele insiste em remover o primeiro elemento até não existir mais um primeiro elemento.

Comment: Muito obrigado!